# Java alphabetizing three cities using if else statements and compareTo

Tags: java, alphabetized

Hi I'm super lost as to how you would compare three things. The textbook example is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
String city1 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
String city2 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the third city: ");
String city3 = input.nextLine();

if (city1.compareTo(city2) < 0)
  System.out.println("The cities in alphabetical order are:");
  System.out.println(city1);
  System.out.println(city2);

else
  System.out.println("The cities in alphabetical order are:");
  System.out.println(city2);
  System.out.println(city1);
```

So how would you compare a third and alphabetize?

Comment: `Stream.of(city1, city2, city3).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: If you have problems with such basic things, you can do the following: Write 3 city names on cards or pieces of paper, shuffle them, and try to figure you how you would order them. Then, try to Code that. If that doesn't work, come back.

Comment: well you would get 9 different possibilities i believe.

Comment: Either sort them .... or *work out* a way to do it using if / else.  Hint: the latter is not difficult, and you can simplify the problem using assignment statements.  Start by selecting the first city.

Comment: Hint 2: your example code is missing {} blocks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort *alphabetical*, the term is **lexicographical**, by using built in sorting algorithms (or your own). For example by using `Collections#sort` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)). Note that `String`s are comparable and use the **lexicographical order** by default. That is why you do not need to explicitly specify the order, for example by using a `Comparator` object.

This snippet sorts the cities and prints them:

```
List<String> cities = Arrays.asList({city1, city2, city3});
Collections.sort(cities);

System.out.println("Cities sorted lexicographical:");
for (String city : cities) {
    System.out.println(city);
}
```

Or if you prefer a compact **Java 8** solution using `Streams` (it essentially falls back to the same methods, especially the same sorting method):

```
Stream.of(city1, city2, city3).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Note that the `String#compareTo` method also compares for lexicographical order, as said before. So instead of using a sorting algorithm (which checks the results of `compareTo` in a clever way) you can also directly hardcode the comparisons (like you already tried):

```
String smallestCity;
if (city1.compareTo(city2) < 0 && city1.compareTo(city3) < 0) {
    smallestCity = city1;
} else if (city2.compareTo(city1) < 0 && city2.compareTo(city3) < 0) {
    smallestCity = city2;
} else if (city3.compareTo(city1) < 0 && city3.compareTo(city2) < 0) {
    smallestCity = city3;
} else {
    throw new AssertionError("There is no strict order!");
}

String biggestCity;
if (city1.compareTo(city2) > 0 && city1.compareTo(city3) > 0) {
    biggestCity = city1;
} else if (city2.compareTo(city1) > 0 && city2.compareTo(city3) > 0) {
    biggestCity = city2;
} else if (city3.compareTo(city1) > 0 && city3.compareTo(city2) > 0) {
    biggestCity = city3;
} else {
    throw new AssertionError("There is no strict order!");
}

String middleCity;
if (city1.compareTo(smallestCity) > 0 && city1.compareTo(biggestCity) < 0) {
    middleCity = city1;
} else if (city2.compareTo(smallestCity) > 0 && city2.compareTo(biggestCity) < 0) {
    middleCity = city2;
} else if (city3.compareTo(smallestCity) > 0 && city3.compareTo(biggestCity) < 0) {
    middleCity = city3;
} else {
    throw new AssertionError("There is no strict order!");
}
```

The method `String#compareTo` returns `0` if the elements are equal, `< 0` if the first element is smaller and `> 0` if greater than the second element ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)).

But as said, a sorting algorithm performs these checks in a **far more clever way**, with **less comparisons**. So you should use one.

Comment: Was thinking of using the && like you did. I know there are much simpler ways of doing it such as arrays and stuff. But haven't gotten to arrays yet. 1st semester in coding.

Comment: Getting the complete order of 3 elements in **a clear way** requires some code, as seen above. But it is possible and quite easy.

Comment: Oh nvm makes sense u did three different methods to each city

Comment: Yes. This is a *clear way* but it requires many unnecessary comparisons. Indeed you can sort those cities with only 4 comparisons or something small like this. If the answer was useful please consider **up-voting** or even **accepting** it, thanks.